# wordpress and facebook open graph

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I am using wordpress and have a rewrite rule working normal before when I share a post to facebook, however i found that facebook now captures only my homepage(http://www.example.com) no matter whatever the post i try to share.

So I checked the HTTP header and it returns 302 to my homepage. Actually it works normal when I browse the site with any browsers. Plsss kindly help

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook Captures the url from it's meta property og:url and you have to set this property in the head tag. If you set your article's link properly with all required og properties then it'll be posted with the accurate link. I think you should read the documentation at [open graph key concepts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/keyconcepts/).

Comment: i have set og:url already. and tested in open graph debug. it shows: Redirect Path

original: http://example.com/blog/
302: http://example.com/

Comment: Can you post me your site link here.

Comment: sure, 
http://socialite.hk/afterparty/?slug=hong-kong-fur-design-competition-2012-2&id=30
Facebook Debug:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fsocialite.hk%2Fafterparty%2F%3Fslug%3Dhong-kong-fur-design-competition-2012-2%26id%3D30

Comment: Now what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The linter returns the home page url isn't it?

Comment: I actually added <meta property="og:url" content="http://socialite.hk/afterparty/?slug=hong-kong-fur-design-competition-2012-2&id=30" /> in header, so I expect facebook could detect it.

Comment: But it detects the base url, right ? I'm confused but will try.

Comment: Thanks a lot! As I see in facebook debug, it shows a Redirect Path from "http://socialite.hk/afterparty/?slug=hong-kong-fur-design-competition-2012-2&id=30" to "http://socialite.hk/"

Comment: Have you used any redirect to force an user to be landed on any special page ?

Comment: OMG! You just reminded me. thanks!! =)

Comment: Welcome ! Hope you got the solution.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to stop all the heavy lifting and install Wordpress SEO by Yoast. It has a built in Facebook Open Graph system.

[wordpress seo](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/)